# migrating oracle trigger to mysql

Tags: mysql, oracle, triggers

I am migrating one of my oracle trigger to mysql, bit its is giving error while migrating.
Below is the oracle trigger overrview. In oracle they have used exception handling. Is there a way we can use the same in mysql:

```
create
TRIGGER {trigger_name}
 BEFORE INSERT ON {table_name_1}
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
   DECLARE sta_ varchar(20);
-- get status
{select statement}
  END
into sta_ from dual;


   INSERT INTO {table_name_2}
   .........
   ........;

     exception(if duplicate entry in table_name_1)


   UPDATE table_name_2
   SET  ..........
   ..........;

   UPDATE table_name_2
   SET  ...........
   .............
   ..........;
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
           RAISE;
END;
```

Comment: There's [DECLARE...HANDLER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/declare-handler.html).

Comment: I don't think this exact behaviour can be replicated in MySQL: duplicate key exceptions raised during data insertion cannot be handled within a trigger for that insertion.